# Calling inherited method - compiler error

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a problem with calling an inherited method. Probably I miss some `virtual`, `const` or `&` but I cannot find where

I have a base class `Classifier` with one "real" and one virtual function, the "real" function calls the virtual one. The child class `MyClassifier` defines the virtual inherited methon. Now when I call the "real" class on the `MyClassifier` object, I get compiler error.

```
class Classifier {
    public:
    bool classify(const Image& ii) 
    { 
        return classify(ii, ii.getRect()); 
    }

    virtual bool classify(const Image& ii, const rect_t& rect) const = 0;
};

class MyClassifier : public Classifier {
    public:
    bool classify(const Image& ii, const rect_t& rect) const;
};

bool
MyClassifier::classify(const Image& ii, const rect_t& rect) const
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

The calling code is:

```
// main...
MyClassifier c;
Image some_image;

c.classify(some_image);
```

And the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClassifier::classify(const Image&) const’
note: candidate is:
note: virtual bool MyClassifier::classify(const Image&, const rect_t&) const
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: @Jakub To really use virtual mechanism of C++ you'd need to use pointers.

Comment: The only thing I care is to have 1-parameter `classify` calling tits 2-parameter version for each inherited class. For me it can be with or without `virtual`. Without even better as I won't get `vtable` performance penalty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overloaded method in the subclass hides the method from the base-class. You can fix it with a `using`-declaration:

```
class MyClassifier : public Classifier {
public:
    using Classifier::classify;
    bool classify(const Image& ii, const rect_t& rect) const;
};
```

Comment: And for the OP, here is more detail than you probably want to know right now about name hiding: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can either add a `using` declaration as in Björn Pollex's answer, or an explicit qualifier at the call site:

```
c.Classifier::classify(some_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the scope operator to specifically indicate that you are trying to call the base class version of the function and not the current class version.